# C++ console application class syntax issue

Tags: c++

I have issue with my code. Below code works as I do not create additional header and .cpp and write in single window in console application.

But when I do something like this I get multiple errors could you help me solving this issue?

I believe something is wrong when I am using list as compiler suggest me to write list; but I have no experience in solving this.

Screenshot:
[image]

```
// A class that represents an undirected graph
class MyGraph
{
    int V;    // No. of vertices
    list<int> *adj;    // A dynamic array of adjacency lists
    int* result;
    bool* available;


public:
    // Constructor and destructor
    MyGraph(int V) {
        this->V = V;
        adj = new list<int>[V];
        result = new int[V];
        available = new bool[V];
    }

    ~MyGraph() {
        delete[] adj;
        delete[] result;
    }

    // function to add an edge to graph
    void addEdge(int v, int w);

    // Prints greedy coloring of the vertices
    void greedyColoring();
};

void MyGraph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w);
    adj[w].push_back(v);  // Note: the graph is undirected
}

// Assigns colors (starting from 0) to all vertices and prints
// the assignment of colors
void MyGraph::greedyColoring()
{


    //int result[V];
    //result = new int[V];

    // Assign the first color to first vertex
    result[0] = 0;

    // Initialize remaining V-1 vertices as unassigned
    for (int u = 1; u < V; u++)
        result[u] = -1;  // no color is assigned to u

                         // A temporary array to store the available colors. True
                         // value of available[cr] would mean that the color cr is
                         // assigned to one of its adjacent vertices

                         //bool available[V];
    available = new bool[V];

    for (int cr = 0; cr < V; cr++)
        available[cr] = false;

    // Assign colors to remaining V-1 vertices
    for (int u = 1; u < V; u++)
    {
        // Process all adjacent vertices and flag their colors
        // as unavailable
        list<int>::iterator i;
        for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
            if (result[*i] != -1)
                available[result[*i]] = true;

        // Find the first available color
        int cr;
        for (cr = 0; cr < V; cr++)
            if (available[cr] == false)
                break;

        result[u] = cr; // Assign the found color

                        // Reset the values back to false for the next iteration
        for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
            if (result[*i] != -1)
                available[result[*i]] = false;
    }

    // print the result
    for (int u = 0; u < V; u++)
        cout << "Vertex " << u << " --->  Color "
        << result[u] << endl;
}


// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    MyGraph g1(5);
    g1.addEdge(0, 1);
    g1.addEdge(0, 2);
    g1.addEdge(1, 2);
    g1.addEdge(1, 3);
    g1.addEdge(2, 3);
    g1.addEdge(3, 4);
    cout << "Coloring of graph 1 \n";
    g1.greedyColoring();

    MyGraph g2(5);
    g2.addEdge(0, 1);
    g2.addEdge(0, 2);
    g2.addEdge(1, 2);
    g2.addEdge(1, 4);
    g2.addEdge(2, 4);
    g2.addEdge(4, 3);
    cout << "\nColoring of graph 2 \n";
    g2.greedyColoring();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the broken code.  Giving us code that works but errors from code that doesn't is not helpful.

Comment: looks like you've not included `<list>`

Comment: `using namespace std;` in header file, or when using `list` and others , use `std::list` instead

Comment: using namespace std solved , thank you Raxvan